# Click open menu width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a click open menu. The menu working well but i want to make it `width:100%` (*for now the menu* `max-width:160px;`). How can i open menu `width:100%;` ?

This is my working **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/OVbNEK)**.

HTML

```
<div class="dd">
<a href="#" class="drop">
 <svg class="icon" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" id="Layer_1" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="5" r="2"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="19" r="2"></circle>
  </svg>
 </a>
  <div class="dd-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Profile & status</li>
       <li>Notification</li>
       <li>Help</li>
       <li>Log out</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:Arial;
  background:#ececec;
}

.drop {
  float:right;

}

.dd {
position:relative;
background:#404BB3;
  padding:20px;
  width:25%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
  height:68px;
}

h1 {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  font-size:26px;
}
small {
 font-size:14px;
  color:#666;
  font-weight:normal;
}
svg {
  height:24px;
  width:24px;
}
svg circle {
 fill:#FFF; 
}

.dd-menu {

position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  right:0;    /*changed here*/
  width:100%;  /*changed here*/
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
}
.dd-menu ul {
   min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
list-style: none;
  position:relative;
}

.dd-menu.active {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
}

.dd-menu li {
  color:#666;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
height: 24px;
list-style: none;
  opacity: 0; 
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
.dd-menu li {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateY(-30%);
}
.dd-menu.active li {
  opacity: 1; 
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Comment: so you want the menu that opens with the three circles to take up the width of the whole page yes?

Comment: @blairmeister  yes i want to make like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to give width as 100%. It will take the 100% page width.

Working [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJNZYa).

Here's a changed CSS from your code:

```
.dd-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  right:0;    /*changed here*/
  width:100%;  /*changed here*/
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
}
```

**EDIT**: with .dd having 25% width.
Here's the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVWLPo).

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working well. but can i ask you something if i can change the `.dd {width:25%;}` what can i do on that time for the `.dd-menu {width:100%;}` ?

Comment: It will span 100% of .dd whatever is its width 25% or 100%. I mean if you give .dd 25% width. Then .dd-menu will still cover its full width. Check the new pen I have updated.

Comment: I understood all your comment and answer. But sorry for my english. My question is for example Please Click [THIS DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/OVbNEK) and change your browser width minimum size and click the menu button then see what is wrong on here.

Comment: The menu shrinks and displays only 25% of the page width. Can you tell what you want to achieve more clearly. Is [THIS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waoexJ) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
.dd-menu {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
}
```